# ASP.NET Core ADFS Authentication Not Authenticating

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, adfs

I've followed instruction from the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-3.1 for ADFS Authentication without Identity Framework.

My application makes the call to the ADFS server and returns a token without an error, but returns to the Home page and not the page that initiated the authentication call. After receiving the token, trying to navigate to the page that requires authorization makes another call to the ADFS server, responding with another token, and returning to the Home page again. I can never navigate to the Internal page.

Do I need to setup some time of handling of the token? After using ADFS in ASP.NET MVC, I was under the impression that the original call was enough and the token persisted until closing or timing out.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
                .AddWsFederation(options =>
                {
                    options.Wtrealm = Configuration["wsfed:realm"];
                    options.MetadataAddress = Configuration["wsfed:metadata"];
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        SaveSigninToken = true
                    };
                })
                .AddCookie();
```

Internal Controller

```
 [Authorize]
    public class InternalController : Controller
    {
```

Comment: Did you managed to solve this?